# Delay between Jquery functions execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, delay

There are 2 buttons on my page: `#signin and #signup`. Click functions for them look like code below. The problem is, when you continously click on them, appearing big delay between functions' execution. Is there anyway to execute them at the same time?

```
var counter = 0,signin = $("#signin"), signup = $("#signup"), signin_f = $("#signin_form"), holder = $("#holder"), signup_f = $("#signup_form"), f_container = $("#form_container"); 
$(".button").click(function () {
        if (counter === 0) {
            signin.removeClass('default_radius').addClass('right_radius');
            signup.removeClass('default_radius').addClass('left_radius');
            $("#first").animate({
                marginTop: "-=150px",
            }, 500);
        }

    });

    $("#signup").click(function () {
        if (counter === 0) {
           holder.addClass('red_border').height(275).slideDown("slow");
           f_container.show();
           signup_f.fadeIn(1200);
        } else {
           holder.animate({height:"275"},1000).switchClass( "green_border", "red_border", 1000 );
           signin_f.fadeOut(500);      
           f_container.animate({height:"260"},1000);
           signup_f.fadeIn(1000);
        }
        counter++;
    });

    $("#signin").click(function () {
        if (counter === 0) {
            holder.addClass('green_border').height(125).slideDown("slow");
            f_container.show();
            signin_f.fadeIn(1200);
        } else {
           holder.animate({height:"125"},1000).switchClass( "red_border", "green_border", 500 );
           signup_f.fadeOut(500);                        
           f_container.animate({height:"110"},1000);           
           signin_f.fadeIn(1200);

        }

        counter++;
    });
```

You can see the code in action here: http://tural.no-ip.org . Fast and continuously click on button and you'll se what i'm talking about. External js file: first.js.

Comment: I'd rely on CSS to automatically resize.

Comment: tried with css too. animations stops 1-2 sec while css "reconfiguring" itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop) method before adding another `fade` function. Usage:

```
signin_f.stop(true, true).fadeIn(1200);
//First argument true = Remove queued animations as well
//Second argument true = Immediately finish the current animation
```

Comment: tried no success.  http://tural.no-ip.org . Fast and continuously click on button and you'll se what i'm talking about. External js file: first.js.

Comment: Also add `.stop(true, true)` before `animate()`. Instead, you can also add `signin_f.stop(true, true)` at the beginning of each event listener.